# res/raw files "not found" Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-resources, android-5.0-lollipop

I have my Eclipse ADT environment set up to develop with Android L. Ever since, I've had troubles with my resources. Before then, my application was working just fine with resources explained below.

First, files with digits [0-9] would throw the error "Resources$NotFoundException" along with a slew of others relating to that (package not found when loading resources, etc).

NOW for the main event: res/raw
When I have no files in my res/raw folder, my application runs. When I add in a file, it crashes. Does anyone have any ideas? Till then I'll deal with a workaround but this is getting very annoying.

EDIT 1: here is a portion of my R.java with the app_name (where the first resourcenotfoundexception is thrown) and LogCat. Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide that may help.

EDIT 2: I'm updating as I debug. I've created a new application with one activity (generated by eclipse. I alter the Activity to not use the appcompat-v7 (I'm targeting API 11 and above), remove all traces of using the appcompat libraries (deleting app: and switching themes to Holo.Light).

**When I have no files in the "raw" folder, the app runs fine. I add one named "a.txt" and suddenly crashes. This has to do something with the R.java file, as "raw" is added right before the strings, and the resources that are not found are in the string class.**

```html
public static final class raw {
        public static final int a=0x7f060000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f080018;
        public static final int app_name=0x7f080001;
        public static final int buildroute_subtitle=0x7f08000e;
        public static final int buildroute_title=0x7f08000d;
        /** 
  This file is automatically generated by Crashlytics to uniquely 
  identify individual builds of your Android application.

  Do NOT modify, delete, or commit to source control!

         */
        public static final int com_crashlytics_android_build_id=0x7f080000;
        public static final int complaints_submission=0x7f080012;
        public static final int complaints_subtitle=0x7f080008;
        public static final int complaints_title=0x7f080007;
        public static final int hello_world=0x7f080014;
```

```html
10-21 21:09:04.809: D/DisplayManager(29904): getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 600 x 1024, real 600 x 1024, largest app 1024 x 999, smallest app 600 x 575, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 160, 160.421 x 159.568 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
10-21 21:09:04.809: D/DisplayManager(29904): getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 600 x 1024, real 600 x 1024, largest app 1024 x 999, smallest app 600 x 575, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 160, 160.421 x 159.568 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
10-21 21:09:04.809: D/DisplayManager(29904): getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 600 x 1024, real 600 x 1024, largest app 1024 x 999, smallest app 600 x 575, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 160, 160.421 x 159.568 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
10-21 21:09:04.809: D/DisplayManager(29904): getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 600 x 1024, real 600 x 1024, largest app 1024 x 999, smallest app 600 x 575, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 160, 160.421 x 159.568 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
10-21 21:09:04.819: W/ActivityThread(29904): Application com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
10-21 21:09:04.829: I/System.out(29904): Sending WAIT chunk
10-21 21:09:04.859: I/dalvikvm(29904): Debugger is active
10-21 21:09:05.029: I/System.out(29904): Debugger has connected
10-21 21:09:05.029: I/System.out(29904): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 21:09:05.229: I/System.out(29904): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 21:09:05.429: I/System.out(29904): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 21:09:05.630: I/System.out(29904): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 21:09:05.830: I/System.out(29904): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 21:09:06.040: I/System.out(29904): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 21:09:06.230: I/System.out(29904): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 21:09:06.441: I/System.out(29904): debugger has settled (1497)
10-21 21:09:06.521: W/ResourceType(29904): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f080001
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904): Failure retrieving text 0x7f080001 in package com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f080001
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1057)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1168)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadLabel(ComponentInfo.java:87)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/PackageManager(29904):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 21:09:06.551: W/ResourceType(29904): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f080001
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904): Failure retrieving text 0x7f080001 in package com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f080001
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1057)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1168)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadLabel(ComponentInfo.java:99)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-21 21:09:06.571: W/PackageManager(29904):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 21:09:06.581: D/DisplayManager(29904): getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 600 x 1024, real 600 x 1024, largest app 1024 x 999, smallest app 600 x 575, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 160, 160.421 x 159.568 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
10-21 21:09:06.581: D/DisplayManager(29904): getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 600 x 1024, real 600 x 1024, largest app 1024 x 999, smallest app 600 x 575, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 160, 160.421 x 159.568 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
10-21 21:09:06.591: D/DisplayManager(29904): getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 600 x 1024, real 600 x 1024, largest app 1024 x 999, smallest app 600 x 575, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 160, 160.421 x 159.568 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
10-21 21:09:06.591: W/ResourceType(29904): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0x7f0a0001
10-21 21:09:06.601: D/DisplayManager(29904): getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 600 x 1024, real 600 x 1024, largest app 1024 x 999, smallest app 600 x 575, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 160, 160.421 x 159.568 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
10-21 21:09:06.651: W/ResourceType(29904): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f020025
10-21 21:09:06.651: W/PackageManager(29904): Failure retrieving resources forcom.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey: Resource ID #0x7f020025
10-21 21:09:06.721: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(29904): Parent view is not a TextView
10-21 21:09:06.791: D/DisplayManager(29904): getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 600 x 1024, real 600 x 1024, largest app 1024 x 999, smallest app 600 x 575, 60.0 fps, rotation 0, density 160, 160.421 x 159.568 dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, address null, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
10-21 21:09:06.791: W/ResourceType(29904): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f030008
10-21 21:09:07.762: D/dalvikvm(29904): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
10-21 21:09:18.433: D/AndroidRuntime(29904): Shutting down VM
10-21 21:09:18.433: W/dalvikvm(29904): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41237ac8)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey/com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey.SplashScreen}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030008
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030008
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1883)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3028)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1722)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:360)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1933)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at com.tommcfarlin.occupantsurvey.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:33)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5345)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
10-21 21:09:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):  ... 11 more
```